# jQuery - piece of code causing conflict problems on pages the selector doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, conflict

Okay so I am developing a WordPress theme.  On the single post page I have a comments div which floats down the page using some jquery.  I am also running a modal popup form to log in.  This is completely fine on the single page when the #commentWrapper (selector for the jquery floating effect) exists.  However on pages where there is no #commentWrapper to float, the modal form doesn't work.  I pinned down the problem to this line in my general jQuery call (by removing each line and testing).

Call in general.js, very last call:

```
jQuery('#commentWrapper').stickyfloat({ duration: 300, easing : 'easeInQuad' });
```

Actual plugin it refers to:

```
    $.fn.stickyfloat = function(options, lockBottom) {
            var $obj                = this;
            var parentPaddingTop    = parseInt($obj.parent().css('padding-top'));
            var startOffset         = $obj.parent().offset().top;
            var opts                = $.extend({ startOffset: startOffset, offsetY: parentPaddingTop, duration: 200, lockBottom:true }, options);

            $obj.css({ position: 'absolute' });

            if(opts.lockBottom){
                var bottomPos = $obj.parent().height() - $obj.height() + parentPaddingTop; //get the maximum scrollTop value
                if( bottomPos < 0 )
                    bottomPos = 0;
            }

            $(window).scroll(function () { 
                $obj.stop(); // stop all calculations on scroll event

                var pastStartOffset         = $(document).scrollTop() > opts.startOffset;   // check if the window was scrolled down more than the start offset declared.
                var objFartherThanTopPos    = $obj.offset().top > startOffset;  // check if the object is at it's top position (starting point)
                var objBiggerThanWindow     = $obj.outerHeight() < $(window).height();  // if the window size is smaller than the Obj size, then do not animate.

                // if window scrolled down more than startOffset OR obj position is greater than
                // the top position possible (+ offsetY) AND window size must be bigger than Obj size
                if( (pastStartOffset || objFartherThanTopPos) && objBiggerThanWindow ){ 
                    var newpos = ($(document).scrollTop() -startOffset + opts.offsetY );
                    if ( newpos > bottomPos )
                        newpos = bottomPos;
                    if ( $(document).scrollTop() < opts.startOffset ) // if window scrolled < starting offset, then reset Obj position (opts.offsetY);
                        newpos = parentPaddingTop;
                    $obj.animate({ top: newpos }, opts.duration );
                }
            });
        };
```

If I add an if command to see if the selector exists, it all works.  I would like to know what the problem is for future website however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your `stickyfloat()` method assumes many things, like always being called on a jQuery object that contains at least one element, or that element always having a parent. For instance, consider the following code:

```
var $obj = this;
// ...
var startOffset = $obj.parent().offset().top;
```

If the jQuery object your method is called on is empty, or if its first element has no parent (the method was called on `$("html")`), the code will fail because `parent().offset()` will be `null`.

If you want your method to be more robust, you should not assume *anything* about the object it's called on. A good first step is to make the method chainable, which is always beneficial to your users and will get rid of the first problem. The [recommended way](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring#Maintaining_Chainability) of doing that is:

```
$.fn.stickyfloat = function(options, lockBottom) {
    return this.each(function() {
        var $obj = $(this);
        // The rest of your code.
    });
};
```

Since the code now runs sequentially on each element (if any) through an anonymous function, testing for the parent element's existence can be dealt with by returning early:

```
var $obj = $(this);
var $parent = $obj.parent();
if (!$parent.length) {
    return;  // No parent, continue with next element, if any.
}
// Parent element is safe to use.
var parentPaddingTop = parseInt($parent.css('padding-top'));
var startOffset = $parent.offset().top;
```